# Verify email from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, email-verification

I am new in backend and got a task to verify register email address when user POST `/register` So in **user.controller.js** file I am using **Hash** to make *user.email* address a secret key.

```
const secret = crypto.randomBytes(20);
const hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
                   .update(secret + user.email)
                   .digest('hex');
console.log(hash);

var expires = new Date();
expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + 6);

    user.emailResetToken = hash;
    user.emailExpires = expires;
```

So, after registering , I have following values:-

```
{
    "isVerified": false,
    "_id": "5c3db78774d8ad1124e6056f",
    "fullName": "ABC",
    "email": "abc@xyz.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$7JBeboru2xORj6d8wyR0W.Ulm/7JQs1dyP7H.Mr4lq8FcSP6KVnBa",
    "phoneNumber": "000631",
    "emailResetToken": "c4af02d40b31e6882692e75f85dab9198fbdcc2f132ee7a0ab0bd94420e4dd",
    "emailExpires": "2019-01-15T16:35:51.457Z",
    "saltSecret": "$2a$10$JBeboru2xORj6d8wyR0W.",
    "__v": 0
}
```

So now I am facing two  problems

- I am able to send email of token `emailResetToken` by [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/about/) , but don't know if I am able to pass the token correctly.

  `let mailOptions = {
                      from: '"XYZ" <xyz@gmail.com>',
                      to: user.email, 
                      subject: "User verification ✔",
                      html: 'Click the following link to confirm your account:</p><p><a href="+user.emailResetToken+">Click here to verify</a></p>'
                    };`

  On clicking the email link I am getting a redirect message : `The page you were on is trying to send you to an invalid URL (http://+user.emailResetToken+)`
- Second I am not getting how will I match the `emailResetToken` token with database `emailResetToken` **on click of the above link** so that this `isVerified": false` becomes `true`.

Comment: You need to redirect to some URL in your app which then handles the token. It can be something like http://yourapp.com/?token=c4af02d40b31e6882692e75f85dab9198fbdcc2f132ee7a0ab0bd94420e4dd. More on how to do it is impossible to tell without knowing how your app is structured

Comment: @Imre_G Ok but I have not worked in frontend part yet.  So , I just need to have a click function for now , no redirection. So upon click the `emailResetToken` becomes `true` from `false`.

Comment: You could create a route in Nodejs that does that. Just create the route, that if you go to that route and give the userId or email or some unique identifier with the link. You can query your database with nodejs and change the value from false to true, using the unique identifier.

Comment: @MaxKoning Yes , I did something similar in that but facing few error. I am creating a new post for this.